# HttpListener.IsSupported is false on XP SP3

Tags: c#, .net, httplistener

We are trying to deploy a simple C# (framework 2.0) application which uses `HttpListener` class on a Windows XP SP3 system: the application aborts at initialization because `HttpListener.IsSupported` property is `false`.

**Question:** what could make `HttpListener` unsupported on a (reasonably) up-to-date XP system ?

Things that could matter:

- User is not administrator on his system
- There may be security policies on the computer which I'm not aware of (and which I'm not sure I am able to check without being administrator myself)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, under the hood `HttpListener` class calls

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct HTTPAPI_VERSION
{
    internal ushort HttpApiMajorVersion;
    internal ushort HttpApiMinorVersion;
}

[DllImport("httpapi.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError=true, ExactSpelling=true)]
internal static extern unsafe uint HttpInitialize(HTTPAPI_VERSION version, uint flags, void* pReserved);
```

On XP:

```
version.HttpApiMajorVersion = 2; 
version.HttpApiMinorVersion = 0;
flags = 5;
pReserved = null;
```

Which is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364488%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). And sets `bool supported = HttpInitialize(...) == 0;`

You can try to call it directly using PInvoke and check [system error code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returned

Answer (score 0):

One possibility: XP Embedded does not seem to be supporting HttpListener/http.sys even with SP2 and later.