# Which windows services are required to start System.Net.HttpListener on a XP machine?

Tags: .net, windows-services, dependencies, httplistener

on some of our customers WinXP SP3 machines, theres a strange behaviour occuring nearly daily.

We've installed a windows service thats executing the following code on startup:

```
if( !HttpListener.IsSupported )
{
    throw new Exception( string.Format( "HttpListener is not supported on {0}.", Environment.OSVersion ) );
}

_httpListener = new HttpListener();
_httpListener.Prefixes.Add( "http://localhost:20001/" );

_thread = new Thread( new ThreadStart( StartListening ) );
_thread.Start();
```

Now sometimes when Windows starts, the code is throwing the "Not Supported" Exception. After stopping and starting the service again, the HttpListener works!

Are there any service dependencies my windows service needs?

Comment: I think your question got answered already : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10026387/httplistener-issupported-is-false-on-xp-sp3

Comment: saw that, but the oddity here is, that httplistener is working after stopping and starting the service. It just looks like some other dependend http service sometimes starts slower than my service..

Comment: Ok I see. Maybe a problem with your http.sys driver ? Gonna check that on the web too, I'd be interested to know the answer as well. Maybe you should have a look here : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/437733/Demystify-http-sys-with-HttpSysManager and ask these guys the question, they may know more about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution!

In the ServiceInstaller constructor just add the following line:

```
serviceInstaller.ServicesDependedOn = new string[] { "HTTP" };
```

That makes your own Service dependend on the Windows HTTP Service and just starts when the HTTP Servive has successfully started.